# what's the difference between using jquery .submit() and a jquery form plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've seen a lot of members of this community recommend something like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){

  $.ajax({
    url:"script.php",
    type: 'POST',
    success:function(data){
      // data returned from php
    }
  });

  return false;

});
```

It seems lightweight, easy to understand and easy to use.

My question: how is the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) useful, if this all can be done that easily?